# Error causing JBoss Developer Studio 6.4 to close

Tags: jboss

I am currently working on JBoss Developer Studio 6.4 and have been receiving an error that automatically closes the program. It happens with varying frequency ranging from every other day to every 5 minutes. After closing, it leaves the attached error window popped up. Please help!
[Error left after the program closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAkcn.png)

Comment: You will probably need to contact the developer about this to get an answer. I'm not sure anyone here can tell you how to fix it when it seems to be a problem directly related to the program.

Comment: I figured that would most likely be the issues, but I was hoping that I would be able to find someone who knew what the error was saying, or had fixed it themselves.